# Error during uploading a file with php

Tags: php

Ok, I used google over the last 2 days and didn't got what is wrong with my code. First it seemed that I used the wrong path but the official "Hilfe Center" (like helping center or so) from 1&1 said that this must be the right path "e:\Kunden\Homepages\11\d12345678\www\UploadTest" (obviously you have to adapt it to your path, which i got throught phpinfo() )
so I'm using the following code:

```
<form action=\"upload.php\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\"> 
                <input type=\"file\" name=\"datei\"><br>
                <input style=\"position:absolute;left:5px\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Hochladen\"> 
                </form>
```

on the site where you upload the file and

```
$max_filesize = 524288; // Maximum filesize in BYTES (currently 0.5MB).
  $upload_path = "e:\\Kunden\\Homepages\\11\\d12345678\\www\\UploadTest";


   $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).


   if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
      die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.'); // if we upload large file then we get error.
   if(!is_writable($upload_path))
      die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.'); // if we have no enough permission then got error.

   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename)){
                    // if everything is fine then we upload file and go to somewhere else
         header ('location: whereeveryouwantogo.php');
     } else {
         echo 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.';
    }
```

on the site where the php script is running (upload.php). I got the code on another thread here and wanted to use it for troubleshooting. Later I'm going back to my own code.

I am now at the last error:

'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.';

I just want to upload .txt files that are later used on a news based site. Thx for any helps in advance!

Comment: How do you think what would be the result of concat `$upload_path . $filename`?

Comment: I'm getting "e:\Kunden\Homepages\11\d12345678\www\UploadTest"

Comment: SO - where is `$filename`? You printed just `$upload_path`

Comment: echo($upload_path . $filename);
so I'd say there is the problem?! let me check it

Comment: ANd what's the result of this `echo`?

Comment: that what i posted "e:\Kunden\Homepages\11\d12345678\www\UploadTest"

Comment: So try to understand where is `$filename`

Comment: ok when i use 
    $_FILES["datei"]['error']
i get error 6 which means no temporary folder... hmm what does that mean?
or better said, how can i fix this?

Comment: Check in php.ini what's the path to temporary folder and check if it's really exists.

Comment: where's the backslash between `$upload_path` and `$filename` ?

Comment: I added it and still the error :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is name of the input or name of the files variable.
$files=$_FILES['datei']['tmp_name'];